# Ansible script to copy file from multiple servers

Tags: ansible

Just wanted to understand what method you could have used to copy a directory from 5-10 remote hosts to a destination say a jump server?

One that I have been working on is:

```
---

 - hosts: all
   gather_facts: true

   vars:
     src_path: "/source_path/"
     dest_path: "/destination_path/{{ inventory_hostname }}/"

   tasks:
    - name: Copy a location from REMOTE server to the LOCAL jump box
      tags: sync-pull
      synchronize:
        # The synchronize module forces–delay-updates to avoid leaving a destination in a broken in-between state if the underlying rsync process encounters an error.
        src: "{{ src_path }}"
        dest: "{{ dest_path }}"
        mode: pull       # In pull mode the remote host in context is the source.
        delete: yes      # Delete files in dest that don't exist (after transfer, not before) in the src path. This option requires recursive=yes.
        recursive: yes
        compress: yes    # Default yes.  Compress file data during the transfer
        times: yes       # Preserve modification times
        rsync_timeout: 15 # Specify a --timeout for the rsync command in seconds.
        rsync_opts:
         - "--exclude=.git"
         - "--exclude=*.log"
         - "--exclude=*.log.gz"
```

There are number of things still trying to figure out.  Some of them are :

1) how to ensure path is selected based on the host.. i.e. Host1 has 3 source_path.  I am not sure how this will be done!

2) If source_path don't have required permission, then script is failing with error:

send_files failed to open \"source_path/iamlog.log\": Permission denied (13)\
Unable to figure out what can be done here!

Answer (score 0):

First thing to check would be file permissions on the file you are trying to copy, it looks like the file is not copying due the user running the ansible-playbook not having permission to read that file.

Check with

`ls -lhtra iamlog.log`

Worst case temporarily give full permissions to everyone to see if it then works:

`chmod 777 iamlog.log`

If it then works you may need to add the ansible-playbook executing user to a local group on the servers to give access or run as the user owner of that file. HTH.